# Deselectable radio not tracking previous value correctly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a simple directive that I can apply to an existing radio input to make it deselectable...it doesn't quite work as the directive is not tracking the previously clicked value correctly. The goal is to have the radio set to 'true', 'false', or null if the currently selected value is the same as the previous (clicking true twice for example will unset the radio and set the model value to null). It seems to continually lose track of the previous value which gets set to undefined. I think I'm maybe making some kind of scoping issue but I'm not sure.

Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('App').directive('deselectableRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            model: '=ngModel'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var previousValue = angular.copy(scope.model);
            element.bind('click', function(e) {
                determineState(element[0]);
            });
            function determineState(elem) {
                if (elem.checked && elem.value == previousValue) {
                    elem.checked = false;
                    scope.model = null;
                }
                previousValue = angular.copy(scope.model);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the HTML:

```
<div class="app-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle-yes" value="true"
           ng-model="props['toggle']" deselectable-radio>
    <label for="toggle-yes">Yes</label>
</div>
<div class="app-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle-no" value="false"
           ng-model="props['toggle']" deselectable-radio>
    <label for="toggle-no">No</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The directive is fighting the ng-model controller.

Instead of creating an isolate scope and a two-way binding to the `ng-model` attribute, use the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#ngModel.NgModelController-methods).

[The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/QT1ijoAvavTEjLSNnUyP?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app',[])
.directive('deselectableRadio', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: false,
        //scope: {
        //    model: '=ngModel'
        //},
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on('click', function(e) {
                if (attrs.value == ctrl.$viewValue) {
                  ctrl.$setViewValue(null);
                  ctrl.$render();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div class="app-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle-yes" value="true"
               ng-model="props['toggle']" deselectable-radio>
        <label for="toggle-yes">Yes</label>
    </div>
    <div class="app-radio">
        <input type="radio" name="toggle" id="toggle-no" value="false"
               ng-model="props['toggle']" deselectable-radio>
        <label for="toggle-no">No</label>
    </div>
    <br>
    model = {{props.toggle || 'null'}}
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @georgeawg - I'm still having some issues though, although I can see that it works in the demo. It seems like when I run it in the project, every time it gets to the check in the click function where it compares: attrs.value == ctrl.$viewValue they are always equal. It seems like attrs.value and ctrl.$viewValue get set together, at least in my environment...we are on a very old version of angular (1.2) if that could have something to do with it.